# Поведение функции srt_replace()

Tags: php, массивы, строки, функции

В документации  к функции str_replace() сказано,  что она возвращает либо массив либо строку http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php.
Суть вопроса в том, что не понятно, при каких условиях возвращается строка и при каких массив? Из документации не понятно, на других сайтах тоже не смог найти информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно понимаете мануал. Вдумайтесь

> Если subject является массивом, то поиск с заменой будет осуществляться над каждым элементом subject, а результатом функции также будет являться массив.

Если сами передаете массив, то и вернется массив, иначе строка

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.  Разобрался. От себя добавлю, что если в replace передан массив, то функция тоже вернет массив.